# Unity terrain - трава и деревья

Tags: unity3d, terrain

Как удалить вот эту траву, но не всю?

[image]

Где же лежит инструмент для удаления?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Выбрать инструмент которым накладывали траву.
2. Зажать Shift.
3. Зажать левую клавишу мыши, предварительно наведя на область, где надо удалить.